# Subclass of LinkedHashMap as cache

Tags: java, inheritance, intellij-idea, collections, delegates

In java library [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) has a method

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest)
```

with description

> Returns true if this map should remove its eldest entry. ... This is useful if the map represents a cache

So, LinkedHashMap has protected method one can use for creating cache.

Like this:

```
public final class LinkedHashMapCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  private final int MAX_LENGTH = 1000;

  @Override
  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
    return size() > MAX_LENGTH;
  }
}
```

But my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) highlights my code with message from inspection:

> Class 'LinkedHashMapCache' explicitly extends
>   'java.util.LinkedHashMap'

The IDE's internal name for the inspection (e.g. used when ignoring it, and in its XML config files) is `ClassExtendsConcreteCollection`, and the title and description are:

> *Class explicitly extends a Collection class*
>
> Reports any clases which
>   extend concrete classes of type java.util.Collection or java.util.Map.
>   Subclassing collection types is a common practice of novice
>   object-oriented developers, but is considerably more brittle than
>   delegating collection calls.

Question: Is it good idea to subclass LinkedHashMap and suppress inspection? Or I need another solution?

My real removeEldestEntry method really more complex than in example, I need to check not only size of map, but some variables in value of Entity.
So, I need custom (but simple) cache.

Comment: Do you know the rationale behind the warning? ("always" and "never" rules are usually wrong)

Comment: Eclipse gives no warning for this class

Comment: You use IDEA, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inspection's text in fact doesn't explain the real danger.

The real danger of extending collection classes is for instance to omit to override *all* methods. For instance, you override `.put()` but not `.putAll()` when extending a `Map` concrete implementation; nothing guarantees that the class you extend will use `.put()` as a "`.putAll()` backend", so you should override both.

In your case, though, you have no such worries.

The inspection is however right that it is more "brittle" to extend than to delegate. In fact, Guava has a lot of classes dedicated to "collection delegation", which delegate by default: `ForwardingMap`, `ForwardingList` etc etc; you then override only the methods you need from this "delegator".

Answer (score 2):

I think this advice may be good in general but not for LinkedHashMap since protected method clearly suggests that this class is designed for subclassing